# How to enforce MustRunAsNonRoot policy in K8S cluster in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a K8S cluster running in Azure AKS service.

I want to enforce **MustRunAsNonRoot** policy. How to do it?

The following policy is created:

```
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: restrict-root
spec:
  privileged: false
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  runAsUser:
    rule: MustRunAsNonRoot
  seLinux:
    rule: RunAsAny
  fsGroup:
    rule: RunAsAny
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: RunAsAny
  volumes:
  - '*'
```

It is deployed in the cluster:

```
$ kubectl get psp
NAME                            PRIV    CAPS   SELINUX    RUNASUSER          FSGROUP     SUPGROUP    READONLYROOTFS   VOLUMES
restrict-root                   false          RunAsAny   MustRunAsNonRoot   RunAsAny    RunAsAny    false            *
```

Admission controller is running in the cluster:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n gatekeeper-system
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
gatekeeper-audit-7b4bc6f977-lvvfl        1/1     Running   0          32d
gatekeeper-controller-5948ddcd54-5mgsm   1/1     Running   0          32d
gatekeeper-controller-5948ddcd54-b59wg   1/1     Running   0          32d
```

Anyway it is possible to run a simple pod running under root:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name:      mypod
spec:
  containers:
    - name:  mypod
      image: busybox
      args: ["sleep", "10000"]
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
```

Pod is running:

```
$ kubectl describe po mypod
Name:         mypod
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         aks-default-31327534-vmss000001/10.240.0.5
Start Time:   Mon, 08 Feb 2021 23:10:46 +0100
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
```

Why **MustRunAsNonRoot** is not applied? How to enforce it?

EDIT: It looks like AKS engine does not support PodSecurityPolicy ([list of supported policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#what-kubernetes-admission-controllers-does-aks-support-can-admission-controllers-be-added-or-removed)). Then the question is still the same: how to enforce MustRunAsNonRoot rule on workloads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `PodSecurityPolicy` on **Azure AKS cluster** as it has been set for deprecation as of May 31st, 2021 in favor of [Azure Policy for AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-pod-security-on-azure-policy). Check [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-pod-security-policies) for further details:

> Warning
>
> **The feature described in this document, pod security policy (preview), is set for deprecation and will no longer be available
> after May 31st, 2021**  in favor of  [Azure Policy for
> AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-pod-security-on-azure-policy).
> The deprecation date has been extended from the previous date of
> October 15th, 2020.

So currently you should rather use [Azure Policy for AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-pod-security-on-azure-policy), where [among other built-in policies](http://Azure%20Policy%20for%20Kubernetes%20offers%20two%20built-in%20initiatives,%20which%20secure%20pods,%20baseline%20and%20restricted.) grouped into initiatives (an initiative in Azure Policy is a collection of policy definitions that are tailored towards achieving a singular overarching goal), you can find a policy which goal is to [disallow running of privileged containers](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2F95edb821-ddaf-4404-9732-666045e056b4) on your **AKS cluster**.

As to `PodSecurityPolicy`, for the time being it should still work. Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-pod-security-policies#create-a-custom-pod-security-policy) if you didn't forget about anything e.g. make sure you [set up the corresponding `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-pod-security-policies#allow-user-account-to-use-the-custom-pod-security-policy) to allow the policy to be used.

Comment: I believe MustRunAsNonRoot is different than disallow running of privileged containers. You can have non privileged container running as root.