# enforce/disable root pod execution on EKS cluster wide

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

What's the best method to enforce/block root containers running in an EKS cluster running managed nodes and applied to all namespaces (except kube-system) v1.22+ ?  I tried the below but root containers are still able to run.  Is this the latest method https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/security/cluster-level-pss/?

```
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: pod-security
spec:
  privileged: true
  seLinux:
    rule: 'MustRunAs'
    ranges:
      - min: 1
        max: 65535
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: 'MustRunAs'
    ranges:
      - min: 1
        max: 65535
  runAsUser:
    rule: 'MustRunAs'
    ranges:
      - min: 1
        max: 65535
  fsGroup:
    rule: 'MustRunAs'
    ranges:
      - min: 1
        max: 65535
  volumes:
  - '*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is use a tool like kyverno or datree and enforce policies and audit them from the cluster build point

https://kyverno.io/policies/pod-security/baseline/disallow-privileged-containers/disallow-privileged-containers/

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you can use `MustRunAsNonRoot` [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/secure-kubernetes-cluster-psp/), but PSP are deprecated (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-policy/).

Also there is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66110317/how-to-enforce-mustrunasnonroot-policy-in-k8s-cluster-in-aks) which talked about PSP and how to enforce it in AWS.

I hope it helps you!

Comment: that link is for AKS not EKS. agree with you on PSP